# Walks of maximum weight in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, recurrence-relations, directed-graphs

Let $G$ be a finite directed graph with weighted edges and an initial vertex $v_0$. Assume that there exists at least one walk of length $n$ starting at $v_0$ for each $n \ge 1$. (A *walk* is a sequence of vertices such that each vertex is adjacent to the next vertex in the sequence. It can visit the same vertex more than once.)

For each $n \ge 1$, let $f(n)$ denote the maximum weight of a walk of length $n$, starting at $v_0$. I conjecture that there exist positive integers $N$, $p$, and $c$ such that $f(n+p) - f(n) = c$ for all $n \ge N$.

Can anyone provide a proof of this conjecture, or (preferably) a reference that contains such a proof?